# How to remove smell from a new water bottle?

Tags: kitchen, plastics, smell

The new bottle has got a weird smell. I kept the bottle without lid from some time but that didn't help much.

It is a plastic bottle. I washed it with plain water.

What is a quick solution to remove odor from a freshly purchased bottle?

Comment: What is the bottle made out of? Have you tried anything else, like washing the bottle?

Comment: @Alex have edited the question. Perhaps I should wash it with soap first.

Comment: Wash it with hot soapy water then leave to drip dry. If, when dry, the smell remains then fill with water and put in the fridge for 24+ hours. This should remove the smell. Always make sure when not in use that the lid stays off. Keep the bottle somewhere cool and dry when not using and without the lid on.  Hope this helps

Comment: @M_Griffiths Why didn't you post that as an answer? It sounds like it could work. If you post it as an answer we can test it and vote it up, if it works.

Comment: @Alex I have done so now.

Comment: Related: http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/7839/easy-way-to-remove-strong-coffee-smell-in-my-tumbler

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Wash it with hot soapy water then leave to drip dry. If, when dry, the smell remains then fill with water and put in the fridge for 24+ hours. This should remove the smell. Always make sure when not in use that the lid stays off. Keep the bottle somewhere cool and dry when not using and without the lid on.

Comment: Please post a separate answer for each method. (e.g., move the lemon juice freeze method to a new answer) This helps the community show which answers are the best, making the question more helpful for the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Another suggestion would be to freeze the bottle with water and lemon juice inside it, after all has frozen you'll need to empty the bottle and wash with warm soapy water and rinse well.

Answer (score 6):

To remove unwanted smells of a new bottle we have to keep in mind that the substances involved may not be water-soluble. Therefore simply washing may not suffice to remove them.

There are several approaches we can try (if needed also in combination):

- **Vinegar or alcohol from bottom shelf liquor:** Leaving the bottle for some hours filled with vinegar or liquor will effectively remove poorly water-soluble chemicals but it may leave an unwanted other smell instead.
- **Milk:** Fill the bottle with warm milk and let it sit in the fridge over night. Milk is good at taking up lipid-based substances but we will have to throughoughly wash the bottle afterwards to remove all remnants of milk which otherwise would smell worse after a while.
- **Baking soda and water:** putting some teaspoons of baking soda in the bottle to then fill it with water overnight may help in removing some unwanted smells but it will not work good on non-water-soluble substances.
- **Denture cleaner or dishwasher tabs:** The chemicals used in these preparations may also help to remove unwanted smells by additionally breaking up organic substances.

My favourite method definitely is **milk**, because of its potential to bind lipid-soluble chemicals which may be released from the plastic bottle. By this we can be a little bit less concerned about potential harm to our health from an unknown substance we smelled.

Still if it was me I would not take the risk of using a weirdly smelling plastic bottle for drinks, simply because I don't know what chemicals there are, and I can see that more and more substances involved in plastic production were being proven to be harmful.

Answer (score 1):

Pour tea in the new bottle for two or three days. If cover is smelly as well, pour tea in the bowl or container then leave cover in the bowl for two or three days

Answer (score 0):

it is quite common that the new water bottle contains the smell so the best ways are:the first is that rinse the bottle with cold water and then put the warm water in it and then put one table_spoon of the baking soda which is one of the natural smell remover. place it for a night and then wash it properly and leave it to dry completely. the second opinion of mine is that water bottles should be washed and then filled after two or three days so it might not have a bad smell.

Answer (score -3):

Best and simplest way is to put the bottle under steam for 10 minutes nearly....

Comment: Not all plastic bottles will withstand high temperatures - this may easily be a way to destroy instead of clean the bottle.