# Things that I can use in my office to remove the strong smell in my tumbler

Tags: smell, drinks

As the title says, how can I easily remove the strong coffee smell in my tumbler?

Most of the time I used this tumbler for coffee here in my office,but there are also times that I want it to used in drinking water. The problem is it irritates me whenever I am drinking water then smelling this strong coffee!

Things that I've done:

1. Wash it thoroughly, I even soaked it and leave soap inside of it overnight.
2. Put how water in it, then shake it thoroughly.

**Edit:** I've changed the title because most of the answers here seems to forget that I am looking for things commonly found in offices

Comment: what's it made out of, this tumbler - plastic, china, glass?

Comment: Maybe stainless steel? Because if I sealed it completely it can keep the warm for even in a whole day.

Comment: Not necessarily - might be like a thermos flask, glass inside, but either way, try a solution of household soda crystals (dri pak) - one dessertspoon in the beaker, top up with boiling water, leave till it cools right down, then wash it. I'll enter this as an answer...

Comment: Why do you need things from the office?
Why not take your cup home for the night, wash it properly (with the techniques from below) getting the long lasting smell gone, then bring it back to the office smell free.
Then make sure to rinse (/wash) it after every use with coffee?

Comment: Because I didn't bring my office stuff with me whenever I go home, it's not practical.

Answer (score 5):

Baking soda is the usual goto for this, but if you are at the office this might be difficult to procure.

If you have a cafeteria with a salad bar, you might be able to rinse with a 50/50 vinegar/water solution which should help (red or white vinegar, not balsamic).

I've used the hand soap to clean my cup and get rid of a large portion of the smell.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this really works but I think it works for me.

I just put a little amount of very hot water (you can get this from your office dispenser, or thermos) then shake my tumbler for a little while, after that you can throw away that water and notice that it doesn't smell anymore!

This seems to be the most practical way when I am at the office.

Answer (score 1):

Household soda crystals should work - one level dessertspoonful in the beaker, top up with boiling water, leave till its completely cool, empty out, rinse and wash thoroughly.

I mean these things:

http://www.msodistributing.com/soda_crystals.html

if you can get something like it where you are. As you're not 100% certain what its made of, keep an eye on it, in case the solution starts to damage the material of the beaker.

Answer (score 1):

Every office usually has coffee.  If yours does, just grab the grounds out of the coffee maker when it is done running, and pour them into the tumbler.  Add a little water to lightly moisten and let it sit for a few hours.  The smell will be gone.

Comment: I usually just put the coffee grounds in my nostrils. This helps with all smells.